# How to spoof src attribute in video tag in HTML5 as youtube does

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, video-streaming

As we can inspect element and see the src tag and get the video link in browser. How to spoof users with a false url so that, users will not know, the location of video.

For example if we open observe the src tag of this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRXbBwpJIbk

```
src="blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/60c62892-bf05-423b-9665-a3a470e9ea37"
```

But If we open this link again, we get nothing or 404 error if we remove blob in url.

So how is youtube doing this? Or any other method to hide URL?

I observed in Network Panel too. I can't see any particular link to get the video. How to implement this?

Comment: Having `blob:http://` isn't going to return anything, you should research information on domain names and http(s)://  as for `how do they do it?` I'm going to assume the video page on youtube is just one page, this page data will change depending on the given videos parameter in the url. To replace `video.php?v=SRXbBwpJIbk` to `watch?v=SRXbBwpJIbk` can be done using `.htaccess`

Comment: Check out this website, it plays the video successfully using the method you suggest, I don't know why it works there and not for you. http://www.tomshannon.com/

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used

Answer (score 2):

Blob URLs are not real and unique URLs. They point to some memory used in a browser tab and can only be used by that tab or its dependents.

Once the tab is closed, the memory is lost. That's why you can't open that blob URL in a different tab.

YouTube seems to be loading chunks of video via XHR and creates or update blobs with each chunk. Then the browser reads the "streaming" blob as if it were a local file (since YouTube is manually taking care of the loading)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is working for you , but I dont if this blob: is build in in his script. maybe you ask him if he can add it , if it not working for you

https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

This module has great features I use it very often for my blogs

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRXbBwpJIbk
```

to

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/SRXbBwpJIbk
```

*i.e.*, change `/watch?v=` to `/embed/`